# Help building electric generator?

Tags: power, electromagnetism, generator, magnetics, coil

I am in the process of building an electric generator for the first time, and I have found out most of what I need to do, except the following things.

1. Can I have 2 rows of magnets linked together side by side spinning around the stator?

   a. If possible does this change the recommended size of the inner diameter of my coil? (I read it's suppose to be about the width of my magnet)

This is the type of generator i'm building. >https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuKKrVlilVk
Right at the beginning the video shows a rotor with 1 row of magnets going around it. I am wondering if I can add another row of magnets side by side going around the wheel.

So the wheel would look like this.

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-
-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

I am wondering if a positive and negative going across the wire at the same time would like cancel each other out or something.

Comment: Precisely what is "electromagnetic generator"?

Comment: Ok maybe I'm adding extras to the term that make it incorrect. But what I am building is an electric generator. I added magnetic to the it thinking that it still means generating electricity using magnets.

Comment: Much useful information here : practicalaction.org/docs/energy/pmg_manual.pdf

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanx for the article. It did contain some useful information, however it wasn't able to answer my questions since I am actually building a different type of generator. I just posted a link to what it looks like in my main post. If anyone could give me the name for that type of generator i'd appreciate it!

Comment: That thing is weird looking, but I think the most accurate name for it might be a multiphase permanent magnet alternator. I didn't see the entire construction but that seems to be where it's headed. Personally, I think I would have hacked an automotive alternator with some kind of a belt drive.

Comment: This is an example of an edited question that now makes perfect sense but it was never reopened. It was asked on May 11, closed 16.25 hours later, edited 18.25 hours after it was closed. The user came back several times after that (see comments) and after 4 days left for good. He had 108 votes when I first saw it now (December 24th). The question is now perfectly understandable. He essentially asks one question - with a few sub points that do not modify the main question. It should not remain closed, it is not obvious that closing it served any purposes and being closed does the list ....

Comment: .... users a dis-service. The question would benefit from tidying. If the OP had been encourage to do this e'd have a better resource and he may still be here. Maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more magnets, but they have to be aligned with the first row, meaning if the first row is +-+-, after adding the second row it should look like
+-+-
+-+-

This increases the strength of the magnetic field, which means more electricity is generated. 
Alternatively, you could use stronger magnets, which will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought that might be the case wasn't sure though. I guess I won't be using two rows then since that would require a lot of work to get the neo mag's I have to stay close together.

Comment: @bluegman991 You could try stacking the magnets on top of each other to increase their strength. That would generate more electricity without you having to worry about keeping the magnets apart. I tried that once; glue covered rare earth magnets moving around will stick to anything and make a mess.

Comment: Yea. I am thinking of either doing that or just making a generator with 1 stator on each side of the rotor.

Comment: @bluegman991 Have fun building it!